# Laravel Destroy() is not removing any record from DB

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

[Database Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mu5fB.jpg)

This is my controller's index method. When i run the code it does nothing.

```
public function index()
{
  Customer::destroy(1);
  return view('customer');
}
```

Model:

```
<?php namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Customer extends Model {
protected  $guarded = [];
public  $timestamps=false;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure customer with primary key equals to 1 exists?

Comment: @Talha yes it exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `delete` instead of `destroy` like this:

```
Customer::findOrFail(1)->delete();
```

or you can try directly from database using eloquent query builder:

```
Customer::where('id', 1)->delete();
```

Comment: even Better: Customer::findOrFail(1)->delete(); If you do not have any other checks

Comment: You have some Exception?

Comment: Ok. I reedit my entry. Try: `Customer::where('id', 1)->delete();`

Answer (score 0):

You can also write your code like this

```
public function getDeleteTag($id)
    {

        DB::table('tags')
            ->where('id','=',$id)
            ->delete();

    return Response::json(['message' => 'Tag has been deleted successfully!']);

    }
```

Comment: assigning $objTag is not required since you do not use it

Comment: its true, agree with you.